# Using CSS/Bootstrap how to put 2 labels and 1 checkbox side by side? (All 3 components are of different height)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am trying to place 2 labels and 1 checkbox side by side properly aligned. How to achieve this?

Currently they look like this:

[image]

My code:

```
<div onClick={this.onClick} className="col-lg-12">
            <label className="col-lg-5 Legends-alphabet">{data.key}</label>
            <label className="col-lg-4 Legends-code">{data.value}</label>
            <input id={data.key} type="checkbox" className="col-lg-3 Legends-checkbox" checked={this.state.done || this.props.done || false} onChange={this.onChange} />
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.Legends-alphabet{
font-size: 40px;
text-align: right;
}

.Legends-code{
    margin-top: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    /*margin-left: 10px;*/
}

.Legends-checkbox{
    margin-top: 2px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: What kind of alignment vertically i.e middle, center or top?

Comment: @AnmolSandal vertically middle should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `display: 'inline-flex'`

https://codesandbox.io/s/lkvy087mz

Comment: Can you post both divs? How do you use `display: 'inline-flex'`? A small code snippet might be enough

Comment: Yes? Just edit your margins. What exactly are you trying to achieve? How exactly would you like to align them?

Comment: I have got a static list of items and some of the texts in the second label are double-lined. I believe that is what breaking the alignment.

Comment: That might be a problem. It's hard to tell from just having a small sample :)

Comment: No worries. You help me to proceed. TY! :-)